# Google maps adding a zoom variable

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am successfully using the following scripts to mark various points on a map. The only problem is the zoom default is to "zoomed in". i have tried to place the zoom variable "zoom:7" but nothing works please help?

```
 function initialize()
        {
            var default_marker;
            /* Map Style Start */
            var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([
                {
                    stylers: [
                        {hue: '#F4B249'},
                        {visibility: 'simplified'},
                        {gamma: 0.5},
                        {weight: 0.5}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    elementType: 'labels',
                    stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
                },
                {
                    featureType: 'water',
                    stylers: [{color: '#F4B249'}]
                }
            ], {
                name: 'Custom Style',
            });

            var customMapTypeId = 'custom_style';

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                     mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, customMapTypeId],
                }
            });
            map.mapTypes.set(customMapTypeId, customMapType);
            map.setMapTypeId(customMapTypeId);

            /* Map Style End */

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            for (var i in LocationData)
            {
                var p = LocationData[i];
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p[0], p[1]);
                bounds.extend(latlng);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: p[2],
                    icon: p[3]
                });
                if (p[4] == "default")  // Default Marker
                    default_marker = marker;

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(this.title);
                    map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
            }
            $("#btn-click").click(function () {
                google.maps.event.trigger(default_marker, 'click');
            });
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
                google.maps.event.trigger(default_marker, 'click');
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have added the zoom in a wrong place. 
Use

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, customMapTypeId],
    },
});
```

instead of your code

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, customMapTypeId],
    },
});
```

Also you had to provide REQUIRED param center (as described in google-maps api docs)

> There are two required options for every map: center and zoom.

Comment: Also you had to provide REQUIRED param center (as described in google-maps api docs)

Comment: the center param is provided by the marker, i've added full script above

Comment: the center param for marker working ONLY for its position NOT FOR MAP

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have added `zoom` at the wrong place. You have this initialization:

```
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                 mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, customMapTypeId],
            },
        });
```

Maybe you have added the zoom as a member of mapTypeControlOptions, but you need to pass it as a member of the main object passed as the second parameter, like this:

```
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                 mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, customMapTypeId],
            }, zoom: 5
        });
```

Comment: @gareth, please, do not be offended, but I do not believe you. How is my approach different than the answer you accepted, which, by the way was posted later than my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as KLin and Lajos said, you need to specify the zoom property when you initialise the map.

Then you need to remove this line; it will automatically adjust the map's zoom level to fit all the markers, and it will zoom right in as far as it can.  e.g. if you only have 1 marker, it will zoom in to level 18 or so.

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Alternatively, leave it in (it will help center the map correctly on the markers too), but then afterwards, adjust the map's zoom:

```
map.setZoom(7);
```

Comment: map center param is also required )